# How to obtain the quadrupole expression from the dipole expression?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

I need to find the quadrupole expression from the dipole expression. I know that the dipole expression is
$$V(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\vec{p}\cdot (\vec{r} - \vec{r}^\prime)}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}^\prime|^3} $$

Now, I wanna find the quadrupole expression from the above expression. I tried to do the following:

[image: my diagram]

You can see from my diagram that I can use the dipole expression to calulate the potencial at the point as follows:
$$V(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left[\frac{-\vec{p}\cdot (\vec{r} - \vec{r}^\prime)}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}^\prime|^3} + \frac{\vec{p}\cdot (\vec{r} - (\vec{r}^\prime + \vec{t})}{|\vec{r} - (\vec{r}^\prime + \vec{t})|^3}\right] $$

I expanded $\frac{1}{|\vec{r} - (\vec{r}^\prime + \vec{t})|^3}$ into series and got
$$ \frac{1}{|\vec{r} - (\vec{r}^\prime + \vec{t})|^3} = \frac{1}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}^\prime|^3} + \frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}^\prime|^5} \left(|\vec{t}|^2 - 2(\vec{r}-\vec{r}^\prime)\cdot \vec{t}\right) + \cdots $$

Substituting in the expression of the potential

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
V(\vec{r}) &= \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left[\frac{-\vec{p}\cdot (\vec{r} - \vec{r}^\prime)}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}^\prime|^3} + \vec{p}\cdot (\vec{r} - (\vec{r}^\prime + \vec{t}) \left[\frac{1}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}^\prime|^3} + \frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}^\prime|^5} \left(|\vec{t}|^2 - 2(\vec{r}-\vec{r}^\prime)\cdot \vec{t}\right) + \cdots\right] \right] \\
&= \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left[\frac{-3[\vec{p}\cdot (\vec{r} - \vec{r}^\prime)][(\vec{r} - \vec{r}^\prime)\cdot \vec{t}]}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}^\prime|^5} + \frac{\vec{p}\cdot\vec{t}}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}^\prime|^3} + \frac{3[(\vec{r} - \vec{r}^\prime)\cdot \vec{t}][\vec{p}\cdot\vec{t}]}{|\vec{r} - \vec{r}^\prime|^5} + \cdots \right] \quad \text{becasue } \vec{t}\rightarrow 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

And after that I don't know how to proceed, I need to show that the quadrupole expression is given by
$$
V(\vec{r}) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=0}^3\frac{x_ix_j}{r^5}Q_{ij}
$$
when $\vec{r}^\prime = 0$ and $\vec{t}\rightarrow 0$.

Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not set $\vec{r}’=0$ to begin?

Comment: When you model a dipole as $+q$ and $-q$ separated by $\vec a$, you have to let $q\to\infty$ and $\vec{a}\to 0$ while holding their product $\vec{p}=q\vec{a}$ constant. You have to do something similar when you model a quadrupole as nearby opposite dipoles.

Comment: I tried to fix $\vec{r}^\prime$ as well but I don't see how to get to the desired expression. On the other hand, should I make $\vec{p}\rightarrow\infty$ and $\vec{t}\rightarrow 0$?